# Georeferenced PDF using iOS & GDAL

Tags: ios, gdal

I have compiled GDAL 1.11.0 for iOS. I can list all drivers but if I open an known Georeferenced PDF I get an error 4 ... not recognised as a supported file format. I am trying to develop a mapping application using geoPDF files. Here is my code;

```
-(void)gdalTests
{
    NSLog(@"GDAL Testing");

    GDALAllRegister();

    int a = GDALGetDriverCount();

    for (int b=1; b<a; b++) {

       NSLog(@"GDAL Driver (%d) %s",b,GDALGetDriverLongName(GDALGetDriver(b)));
       if (b==95) {
           GDALDriverH drv = GDALGetDriver(b);
           GDALRegisterDriver(drv);
           NSLog(@"PDF DRIVER REGISTERED");
       }
    }

   NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"9030-4N KURRAJONG" ofType:@"pdf"];
   GDALDatasetH dataset = GDALOpen ([filePath cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]], GA_ReadOnly);

}
```

Here is a portion of the output with the error.

```
2015-03-17 16:52:05.800 pdfTest[46322:4110504] GDAL Driver (94) HF2/HFZ heightfield raster
2015-03-17 16:52:05.800 pdfTest[46322:4110504] GDAL Driver (95) Geospatial PDF
2015-03-17 16:52:05.800 pdfTest[46322:4110504] PDF DRIVER REGISTERED
2015-03-17 16:52:05.800 pdfTest[46322:4110504] GDAL Driver (96) OziExplorer Image File
2015-03-17 16:52:05.800 pdfTest[46322:4110504] GDAL Driver (97) USGS LULC Composite Theme Grid
2015-03-17 16:52:05.801 pdfTest[46322:4110504] GDAL Driver (98) Arc/Info Export E00 GRID
2015-03-17 16:52:05.801 pdfTest[46322:4110504] GDAL Driver (99) ZMap Plus Grid
2015-03-17 16:52:05.801 pdfTest[46322:4110504] GDAL Driver (100) NOAA NGS Geoid Height Grids
2015-03-17 16:52:05.801 pdfTest[46322:4110504] GDAL Driver (101) MBTiles
2015-03-17 16:52:05.801 pdfTest[46322:4110504] GDAL Driver (102) IRIS data (.PPI, .CAPPi etc)
ERROR 4: `/Users/michealcumming/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/83827FA6-0626-4A6F-8A43-516AD495430B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/4249E572-0813-4C79-87BF-B1406E139552/pdfTest.app/9030-4N KURRAJONG.pdf' not recognised as a supported file format.
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Trying to do something similar.

Comment: No, sorry could not crack it with GDAL library directly.  I used https://github.com/yllan/YLPDFKit. I will post the code that I used with this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using https://github.com/yllan/YLPDFKit
Here is the code that is used to access the document data.  I hope this helps you.

```
NSString *documentName = @"9030-4N KURRAJONG";
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:documentName ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *documentUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)documentUrl);

CGPDFStringRef string;
CGPDFDictionaryRef infoDict;

infoDict = CGPDFDocumentGetInfo(document);
NSDictionary *d = YLGetDictionaryFromCGPDFDictionary(infoDict);
NSLog(@"DOCUMENT INFO %@",d);

CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, 1);
NSLog(@"#rekt: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox)));

CGPDFDictionaryRef firstPage = CGPDFPageGetDictionary(page);

d = YLGetDictionaryFromCGPDFDictionary(firstPage);

NSArray *viewPortArray = [d objectForKey:@"VP"];
for (NSDictionary *d in viewPortArray) {

    NSString *name = [d objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSLog(@"---- %@",name);
    NSLog(@"%@",d);
}

for (int x = 0; x<5; x++) {

    CGRect box = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, x);
    NSLog(@"PDF BOX %d = %0.4f %0.4f %0.4f %0.4f",x,box.origin.x,box.origin.y,box.size.width,box.size.height);
}
```

Comment: Very helpful!  I will try this tonight.  Are you able to access the geo data?